# Index the middle of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

To index the middle points of a numpy array, you can do this:

```
x = np.arange(10)
middle = x[len(x)/4:len(x)*3/4]
```

Is there a shorthand for indexing the middle of the array?  e.g., the `n` or `2n` elements closes to `len(x)/2`?  Is there a nice n-dimensional version of this?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way other than what you have created. The most similar thing in the library is probably [`np.fft.fftshift`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html) which shifts the array to place the middle at index 0.

Comment: Yeah, that was the other option I had considered, but it's not a ton better: you'd need to do `x = np.concatenate([np.fftshift[:n],np.fftshift[-n:]])` or similar.

Comment: It seems like just making this a function (eg, `mid = lambda x: x[len(x)/4:len(x)*3/4]`) would be the simplest solution.

Comment: You can use slice objects for the n-dimensional case:

`mid = lambda x: x[[slice(np.floor(d/4.),np.ceil(3*d/4.)) for d in x.shape]]`

Comment: @cge Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as [cge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/599265/cge) said, the simplest way is by turning it into a lambda function, like so:

```
x = np.arange(10)
middle = lambda x: x[len(x)/4:len(x)*3/4]
```

or the n-dimensional way is:

```
middle = lambda x: x[[slice(np.floor(d/4.),np.ceil(3*d/4.)) for d in x.shape]]
```

Comment: fast forward 4 years, and this now produces a warning "VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future".

Answer (score 5):

Late, but for everyone else running into this issue:
A much smoother way is to use numpy's `take` or `put`.

To address the middle of an array you can use `put` to index an n-dimensional array with a single index. Same for getting values from an array with `take`

Assuming your array has an odd number of elements, the middle of the array will be at half of it's size. By using an integer division (`//` instead of `/`) you won't get any problems here.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                [3, 4, 5],
                [6, 7, 8]])

# put a value to the center 
np.put(arr, arr.size // 2, 999)
print(arr)

# take a value from the center
center = np.take(arr, arr.size // 2)
print(center)
```